# Which actions should be completed before a package can be moved to another devhub?

Tags: managed-package, migration, partner, dev-hub, 2gmp

My client wasn't a Salesforce partner and delayed a decision to become Salesforce partner and push the package we built for them to AppExchange for three years, now they are ready, but Salesforce security review team noted that Devhub is not connected to their newly created partner account and the package will miss partner benefits if they continue with the current devhub.

So they want now to migrate the package (and its dependent extension packages and related package) to move to another devhub.

It is clear that a Salesforce Support case should be opened for this, but what are the other actions which should be completed before a package can be moved to another devhub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we are going through this and my customer has opened a case and these are the steps which we are doing.

1. We need to link client customer namespace to the new devhub org.
2. We need to remove error notification user from every package we want to migrate by running a command `sfdx package update --package 0Ho00000000PACKAGE --error-notification-username ''`
3. wait for the Salesforce support team to complete the migration/transition.